# Image gets reflected along diagonal axis after pixel value changing in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a python code using **OpenCV** to access an image and then using the `cv2.FindContours` function I extracted all of the contours and filtered the contour with the largest **perimeter**.

My goal is to now turn all of the pixels outside of this contour black and only let pixels which are inside this contour white. For that I used the `cv.PointPolygonTest` function which tells you whether a point is within a polygon or not. But when I wrote my result using `cv2.imwrite`, I was surprised too see the image rotated, and later realized that it was actually a reflected image along the top left to bottom right diagonal.

Since my image is rectangular not square, this causes some of my area of interest to be cutoff. I am attaching the code along with the

Input image

[image]

and the output image

[image]

```
import cv2
import cv
import copy as cp
import numpy

im_gray = cv2.imread('1191res.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
im_gray2 = cp.copy(im_gray)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_gray2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#loop to calculate the relevant contour index
lperimeter = 0
i = 0
x = 0

while (x < len(contours)):
    if(cv2.arcLength(contours[x], True) > lperimeter):
        lperimeter = cv2.arcLength(contours[x],True)
        i = x
    x = x+1

#converting the contours[i] to a type recognized by function cv.PointPolygonTest
result = cv.fromarray(contours[i])

row = len(im_gray)
col = len(im_gray[0])
x = 0

print row
print col

nop = 0
r = 0
c = 0

while r < (row):
    c = 0
    while c < (col):
        if( cv.PointPolygonTest(result,(r,c),False) == -1):
            im_gray[r, c] = 0
            nop+=1
        else:
            im_gray[r, c] = 255
        c+=1
    r+=1
print nop
cv2.imwrite("result1.jpg",im_gray)
```

Comment: Points are `(x,y)`, i.e `(col, row)`. Change your code to: `if( cv.PointPolygonTest(result,(c,r),False) == -1):`

Comment: @Miki ...it worked...thanks....it was quite silly!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest) accepts a `Point`, which is `(x,y)`, i.e. `(column, row)`.

You need to change your code to:

```
if( cv.PointPolygonTest(result,(c,r),False) == -1):
                                ^^^
```

Comment: @Miki....even though the problem is solved....do you have an insight on why the image was being reflected??...i mean c and r are just two numbers....which are being passed to _cv.PointPolygonTest_ function...why should it affect the image??

Comment: Because you are testing on, say, (5,3), but then you set the point (3,5) which will cause the image to be _reflected_.